# Choosing from a multinomial distribution

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution

I recently came across a [paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf) that mentions **Choose a topic z<sub>n</sub> ∼ Multinomial(θ)**. From my understanding of the multinomial distribution parameterized by a probability vector θ, you get the probability of a particular distribution of events (ex: probability of selecting 4 Chinese citizens, 3 Indian and 5 American etc.). How do I interpret the highlighted statement.